Idependecy of identically distributed RV, whose sum is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$
Task: Is it possible for $\xi$ and $\eta$ to be independent and identically distributed, while $\xi + \eta$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0, 1]$?
My professor said that the solution is not very good and that it is inaccurate. Please help me what needs to be fixed?
My solution: No, there do not exist independent and identically distributed random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ such that $\xi+\eta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.
Justification: Assume the contrary. Let $\xi$ and $\eta$ be independent, identically distributed random variables with density $f_\xi(x)$, such that their sum $\xi + \eta$ has a uniform distribution on the interval $[0,1]$. Then the density of the sum can be expressed as a convolution:
$$
f_{\xi+\eta}(x) = (f_\xi * f_\xi)(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_\xi(t)f_\xi(x-t)\,dt.
$$
We require that
$$
f_{\xi+\eta}(x) =
\begin{cases}
1, & x \in [0,1], \\[6pt]
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
Let us consider characteristic functions. Let $\varphi_\xi(t)$ denote the characteristic function of the random variable $\xi$. Then the characteristic function of the sum $\xi+\eta$ is
$$
\varphi_{\xi+\eta}(t) = \varphi_\xi(t)\varphi_\eta(t) = [\varphi_\xi(t)]^2,
$$
since $\xi$ and $\eta$ are independent and identically distributed.
The characteristic function of the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ is given by
$$
\varphi_{U(0,1)}(t) = \int_0^1 e^{itx}\,dx = \frac{e^{it}-1}{it}.
$$
From the condition that $\xi+\eta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$, it follows that
$$
[\varphi_\xi(t)]^2 = \varphi_{U(0,1)}(t) = \frac{e^{it}-1}{it}.
$$
Thus,
$$
\varphi_\xi(t) = \pm\sqrt{\frac{e^{it}-1}{it}}.
$$
However, not every function obtained in this way is a characteristic function of some distribution. A characteristic function must be positive definite, continuous, satisfy $\varphi(0)=1$, and adhere to Bochner's theorem on positive definite functions. It is known that the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ cannot be expressed as the convolution of two identical distributions. Therefore, there does not exist a random variable $\xi$ such that $\xi+\eta \ $ (where $\eta$ has the same distribution as $\xi)\ $ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.
Conclusion: There do not exist independent, identically distributed random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$ such that $\xi+\eta$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$.

Please, take the time to format your question, not just copy-paste a file. Consider that many users of this site won't even read your questions if they are not properly formatted, let alone help you.

If you are allowed to call in that "It is known that the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$
cannot be expressed as the convolution of two identical distributions." why are you further elaborating anything? That is why I also think your proof is not very good. This post contains a few better ones. The comment there by Dilip Sarwate is the slickest but it requires that both rvs have densities.
